# R get N words from a sentence as a string

Tags: r, substring

In R how can I write a function where given a sentence I can pass an integer argument that returns the end words as a character string

EG

```
sentence <- "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
result <- get_words(sentence, 2)
```

result should equal `"lazy dog"`

The function should include guard clauses and return the last word if the total words requested exceeds the words in the sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure `stringi` solution (`stringr::word()` is overkill and uses more `stringi` functions than this. `stringr` handicap-wraps `stringi` functions):

```
library(stringi)

sentence <- "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

tail(stri_extract_all_words(sentence)[[1]], 2)
## [1] "lazy" "dog" 

stri_join(tail(stri_extract_all_words(sentence)[[1]], 2), collapse=" ")
## [1] "lazy dog"
```

Actually readable version:

```
library(magrittr)

stri_extract_all_words(sentence)[[1]] %>% 
  tail(2) %>% 
  stri_join(collapse=" ")
## [1] "lazy dog"
```

It also uses a better, locale-sensitive word-break algorithm which is superior to base R's.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `stringr` library.

```
library(stringr)

sentence <- "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
word(sentence, start = -2, end = -1)
```

Edited after tyluRp's suggestion.

Comment: @akrun just posted at the same time, and then edited it because it was poorly formatted. Didn't copy it.

Comment: You can change it to `paste( word(sentence, -2:-1), collapse=' ')`  Anyway somebody si voting against me although I posted first

Comment: `word(sentence,-2)` returns `lazy` not `lazy dog`, am I missing something?

Comment: This should be modified to `word(sentence, start = -2, end = -1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence <- "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
paste(tail(strsplit(sentence, "\\s+")[[1]], 2), collapse=" ")
```